# ZSH Time Stamp including the (###) milli seconds format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss:###

Tags: date, zsh, milliseconds

How do I get the Time Stamp that includes milli seconds (thousandth of a second) in ZSH?  When I try the BASH syntax, I'm not getting the same result in ZSH.

As you can notice here, **:%3N** produces milli seconds in BASH.

**ZSH**:

```
$ date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%3N %Z"
2017-09-25 13:43:51:

$ date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
2017-09-25 13:42:31 EDT
```

**BASH**:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%3N %Z"
2017-09-25 13:47:18:718 EDT
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with  `bash` vs `zsh`. It is the `date` command itself (an external program) that interprets (or ignores) `%N`. Are you by any chance testing this on two different machines with different implementations of `date`?

Comment: Yes.  I was trying the 'date' command inside an NSH Script used by BladeLogic Server Administration tool. NSH I'm told; uses ZSH for syntax.  Thanks for pointing in the right direction - that 'date' program implementation itself is the reason; not BASH or ZSH.